# User GUID when disconnected from network

Tags: .net, active-directory, guid, sid

I can use this code to get the GUID and SID of the currently logged in user:

```
UserPrincipal user = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current;
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", user.Guid, user.Sid);
```

However, if the user logs in without being connected to the network, that code fails ("The server cannot be contacted."). I can get the SID of that user, even if they aren't connected, like this:

```
WindowsIdentity identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
Console.WriteLine("{0}", identity.User.Value);
```

But the WindowsIdentity object doesn't contain a GUID, as far as I can tell.

**How can I get the GUID of the current user, if they aren't connected to the network?**

NOTE: This is a desktop application, not a web app.

Comment: Can you go into any more detail? I don't really understand how this stuff works. Why can I get the SID if they're not on the network, but not the GUID?

Comment: I'm wondering whether the GUID is only held at the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Security Identificator (SID) is part of each process token, it's the real user identificator. When you are in WorkGroup it's stored in the SAM (Part of the registry) of each computer, when you are in domain it's stored as an attribute of an user object in Active-Directory.

The GUID is also an attribute of an user object in Active-Directory, but it's main purpose it to insure the unicity of this object.

As far as I understand the GUID is not part of Windows security, so I'am not surprise that's it's not available in disconected mode.

Comment: Darn. [This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961625.aspx) says that a user's SID changes when he moves domains, while his GUID will not. I need  to persist a token that represents the user so I can identify him later (a custom authentication scheme operating outside of Windows') and I don't want it broken when he moves domains, and I don't want to have to maintain a SID history list like Windows apparently does. Being able to access that GUID would be very nice.

Comment: As far as I know, the only solution for you is to query the GUID from Active-Directory.

Answer (score 0):

The SID is stored in the user's security token which is why you can access it offline. The GUID is preserved during an intra-forest move (so between domains within the same forest), so using it as your key is a good idea. Since it never changes, why don't you persist the user's GUID to the registry the first time you start the app up?